# how to discards the scalar value in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Please any one tell me how to discards the scalar value in stored procedure?

this is my SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testdata
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT c.CustomerName,c.CustomerCode, a.Address, a.Email,a.phone,a.ZipCode 
    from Customer c
    join Address a on c.CustomerCode = a.CustomerCode
END
GO
```

This is my C# code

```
 CustomerDataEntities enty = new CustomerDataEntities();
        var productEntity = enty.testdata123();

    // error foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type int
    foreach (var prd in productEntity) 
    {

    }
    return CustomerList;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean discard the scalar value? You don't have a scalar value in this procedure.

Comment: what scalar value? are you talking about the return code perhaps?

Comment: I am using C# and Linq to get the resulting data, but I get the following error when I compile:

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: That means that you're trying to loop on an integer, which can't be done because the integer type doesn't implement the `GetEnumerator()` method.

Comment: Can you post your C# code too?

Comment: Please post the C# code for the CustomerDataEntities class

Answer (score 1):

Based just on what you're showing here, I'm assuming your stored procedure is set up as an imported function.  I would guess that you are not mapping the results of this function to an entity type.